# How to convert a html button to a submit button and change its text as well by jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a plain button with input type as button, please see below

```
<input type="button" name="btn" value="clickME">
```

How can I convert the above button to the below 'submit' button using jQuery and also its text i.e the button should change from 'clickMe' to 'Add'

```
<input type="submit" name="btn" value="Add">
```

Comment: just wondering, why don't you set it directly in HTML markup?

Comment: check this fiddle how to change type and text using jquery 
http://jsfiddle.net/8safzhtL/

Comment: Well .. let me tell you , clicking that button would also show/hide a <div> tag. However alongwith that I want that button to be changed to a submit type. How can I do that ?

Comment: add some code which you have already done.

Answer (score 0):

add class to button `<input type="button" name="btn" value="clickME" class="button01">`
in jquery

```
$(".button01").prop('type','submit');
$(".button01").val('Add');
```

Answer (score 0):

Add id "button1".

```
$("#button1").click(function() {
    $(this).attr("type", "submit").val("Add");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply, change its attribute using jQuery check bellow code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btnMyButton').click(function(){
        $('#btnMyButton').attr('type','submit').val('Add');
    });
    
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" name="btn" value="clickME" id="btnMyButton">
```

Comment: Hi shah, The code you posted is working. But the thing is that as I click on the 1st button it is changing it to 'Submit' type and changing its value to 'Add' ...however at the same time it is submitting the page which I do not want. I want it to be changed to 'submit' type. After that if I click explicitly on it then only it should submit.

Answer (score 0):

I am also wondering about your requirement, why did you put the button as a submit button at the time of creation? is there any problems ?  anyway try below code it will give the result

```
$('#btnMyButton').attr('type','submit').val('Add')
```

**OR**

```
 $('#btnMyButton').prop('type','submit').val('Add')
```

if you want to do it in a click event then use the below code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btnMyButton').click(function(){
        $('#btnMyButton').prop('type','submit').val('Add');//prop or attr
    });

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is not to manipulate the dom to change is functionality. This is because your markup isn't reflecting the intention of your page.

That being said...if you still wanted to do this, you can remove it and insert a new element like so...

```
$('input[type=button]').insertAfter('<input type="submit" name="btn" value="Add" />');
$('input[type=button]').remove();
```

However, I think the best way to achieve what you are trying to do is add both the button and the submit input but hide one using CSS or the .hide() function. Then when you want to, hide the button and show the input.

```
$('input[type=button]').hide();
$('input[type=submit]').show();
```